# Flip animation works OK in Chrome but not in Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, css-transforms

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/hy2dvL1u/43/

When you open it in Chrome and click the card it will flip and move to the right. Looks OK in Chrome, but when I do this in Safari (v9) the animation kinda sucks (it has clipping etc, click faster to see the mess-up better)

Part of the CSS (please see the whole in the fiddle):

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
    /*  UPDATED! flip the pane when .flipped class applied */
    .flip-container.flipped .back {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    .flip-container.flipped .front {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 7.1428rem;
    height: 10rem;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 200ms;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}
```

What am I missing? Why is the flipping animation so bad in Safari?

Kind regards,

ps. I don't use the -webkit- prefix since it shouldn't be needed anymore

Comment: As stated in the post version 9

Answer (score -1):

try it

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */

.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/*  UPDATED! flip the pane when .flipped class applied */
    .flip-container.flipped .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-container.flipped .front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 7.1428rem;
    height: 10rem;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 200ms;
    transition: 200ms;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}
```